# How to get one record by decrypting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using an encrypt script. I can store data one by one as encrypt. And I can get all the table data by decrypting using below code.

```
public function alldata(Request $request)
{
  $data = Contact::all();  
  return view('mail.list', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

Now, I have problem. I'm trying to get on record but it didn't decrypt.
Could someone please tell me what is wrong with  my  code below?

```
public function onerecord(Request $request)
   {
      $param = ['id' => $request->id];
      $data = DB::select('select * from contacts where id = :id', $param);       
      return view('mail.one', ['data' => $data]);
   }
```

UPDATES
This is my current code

```
 public function one(Request $request)
    {             
      $data = Contact::find($request->id);
      return view('mail.one', ['data' => $data]);
     }
```

my blade files

```
@foreach ($data as $val)

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $val->id }}</td>
        </tr>

@endforeach
```

Result
using below code

```
public function one(Request $request)
{ 
$data = Contact::where('id',$request->id)->first();
return $request->all(); 
}
```

{
  "id": "1"
}

Comment: Why not use Eloquent like `Contact::find($request->id')` ?

Comment: @Saromase it's better to use eloquent but that's not the issue here,mikancode can you explain/show more how are you encrypting data?

Comment: Dear @Saromase  Thank you for helping me. I still have got syntax error . Could you teach me whole code pleaes?

Comment: Please update the post with the latest Code or Error you faced.

Comment: Dear @Lim Kean Phang Thank you for helping me. I update my current code.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code but what's the error for now? Query error or output data was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is use laravel eloquent

```
public function onerecord(Request $request)
{
  $data = Contanct::where('id',$request->id)->first();       
  return view('mail.one', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

or

```
public function onerecord(Request $request)
{
  $data = Contanct::whereId($request->id)->first();       
  return view('mail.one', compact('data'));
}
```

both of them are same

**Update:**

```
public function onerecord(Request $request)
{
  $data = Contanct::where('id',$request['id'])->first();       
  return view('mail.one', ['data' => $data]);
}
```

or

```
public function onerecord(Request $request)
{
  $data = Contanct::whereId($request['id'])->first();       
  return view('mail.one', compact('data'));
}
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini Thank you for code. but .. I tried both and I got  ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'id' of non-object...

Comment: @mikancode what is your $request? your $request have no id filed in your view.please show me your $request->all()

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini I update my blade file. And sorry I don't understand  show me your $request->all() mean. Could you teach me what should I do ?

Comment: @mikancode write this code in the onerecord method at the top:  (  return $request->all(); ) and tell me what is returned

Comment: @mikancode public function onerecord(Request $request)
{ return $request->all(); }

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini sorry took long time I got thisi --->   id "1"

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini  Thank you update result. I copyed.

Comment: @mikancode now try this code: return $request['id'];   it shows you number 1?

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini  Yes I got number 1 now.

Comment: @mikancode I've update my answare...please check Update section

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini Thank you for update but sorry I still got this error  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/privatebio/www/nak-ivory/order/resources/views/mail/...

Comment: @mikancode if $request['id']; returns to you exactly 1 that means this is your id..are your sure it returns to you just 1???  $id = $request['id']; return $id; what is it returns?

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini Thank you for talking time for me  $id = $request['id']; return $id; is 1   And return $request[0]->id;  is  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object  error.

Comment: @mikancode public function onerecord(Request $request)
{ $id = $request['id'];
  $data = Contanct::where('id',$id)->first();       
  return view('mail.one', ['data' => $data]);
}

Comment: Dear @mohammad Hosseini Thank you for helping me.  I tried your new code but still same error. Yes I have instagram account but I'm beginner . what should I do?